# Cannot retrieve table rows from ASP.Net core razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to C# and ASP.Net core razor pages.  I think this is a simple question but after many hours I still have not been able to resolve it.

I am (currently) putting my business logic (eg Maintenance logic) in  root/BLL/MaintenanceBLL/Maintenance.cs

In trying to read records in the Maintenance table from Maintenance.cs.
I get the error

> CS0030    Cannot convert type 'Club.Models.Maintenance' to
> 'Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL.Maintenance'

The term ForEach is redlined in the code by VS2019.
I cannot resolve this error.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

My code is:

```
Namespace Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL
{
    public class Maintenance
    {
        private readonly Club.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public Maintenance(Club.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public Maintenance()
        {
        }
      
        public void DoMaintenance()
        {
            //Parse Maintenance table and action those items
            //where Active=True and ActionDate has passed
           
            var maintenances = _context.Maintenance;
            foreach (Maintenance m in maintenances)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you've got two different classes, each named the same thing: `Maintenance`.  One solution is to qualify the name, e.g. `foreach (Club.Models.Maintenance m in maintenances) {} `.  A better solution would be to give each different class it's own name, for example rename your example `class MaintenanceBLL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `var` to auto detect type like

```
foreach (var m in maintenances)
```

or

```
foreach (Club.Models.Maintenance m in maintenances)
```

The reason is you must be having two `Maintenance` classes one would be under `namespace Club.Models` and other one under `namespace Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL`.

As your current code is under `Namespace Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL;` when you write `Maintenance` it will try to find `Maintenance m in maintenances` class under current `namespace` or all `namespace` which you have mentioned with `using ...`.

You have not added `using Club.Models;` so it won't find `Club.Models.Maintenance` and your `foreach (Maintenance m in maintenances)` will treated as `Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL.Maintenance`.

But your `_context.Maintenance` would be `DbSet<Club.Models.Maintenance>` so when you write `foreach (var m in maintenances)` it will expect to loop with `Club.Models.Maintenance` object. And you mentioned `Maintenance` which would be considered as `Club.BLL.MaintenanceBLL.Maintenance` so your compiler is showing the `red line` with error.

Comment: Thanks for this Karan and paulsm4 .  Much appreciated.  I will digest your comments and let you know what happens.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, I now understand, so can continue my journey.  Thanks for your prompt responses.  Cheers...and stay safe

Comment: @Alan Laird [How do I accept an answer, and what are the rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)